# How to emphasize an action as in "I don't ..., but I *do* ..."

Tags: tiempos-verbales, solicitud-de-término, comparación-de-idiomas

En inglés se puede utilizar el verbo 'do' como un verbo auxiliar para enfatizar una acción. Por ejemplo:

> You aren't really getting good results at school. - But I *do* study hard.
>   (No estás consiguiendo buenas notas en la escuela. - Pero estudio mucho.)

o

> I don't like listening music, but I *do* play the trumpet.
>   (No me gusta escuchar música, pero toco la trompeta.)

(En estos ejemplos la acción no está enfatizado como me gustaría, en la versión española.)
¿Cómo puedo expresar lo mismo en español, sin utilizar el incómodo palabra 'aunque' como en el siguiente ejemplo?

> No me gusta escuchar música, aunque toco la trompeta.

Simple utilizar 'pero' no expresa suficientemente lo que sigue, en mi opinión.

---

In English we can use 'do' as an auxiliary verb to emphasise an action. For example:

> You aren't really getting good results at school. - But I *do* study hard.

or

> I don't like listening music, but I *do* play the trumpet.

How can I express the same in Spanish, without using the cumbersome 'aunque' as in this example?

> No me gusta escuchar música, aunque toco la trompeta.

Using only 'pero' doesn't emphasize enough what comes next, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En efecto, la traducción gramaticalmente exacta para el uso de «do» como reafirmación positiva de un enunciado es «sí».

Analicemos un poco la gramática:

I *don't* like fish. ↔ *No* me gusta el pescado.

En inglés, para negar, se usa el verbo auxiliar *do* más el adverbio de negación *not*. En castellano es más simple: no necesitamos ningún verbo auxiliar para la negación, basta añadir el adverbio *no* delante del verbo y ya queda negada la oración.

Partiendo de aquí, para reafirmar en inglés se hace igual que la negación pero sin el *not*, y en castellano sencillamente tenemos que transformar el *no* en *sí*. Esto es así porque tanto *no* como *sí* son adverbios, como *quizá*, *también*, *nunca*, *siempre*, *hoy*, *mañana*... Todo eso lo podemos poner delante del verbo sin problemas.

I *do* like fish. ↔ *Sí* me gusta el pescado.

---

Respecto a lo de las calificaciones, *notas* y *calificaciones* son sinónimos (*notas* es una palabra muy genérica, más coloquial para este uso, y *calificaciones* es específica). Puedes usar estas fórmulas:

- No estoy sacando muy buenas notas. (Con *notas* se usa el verbo *sacar*.)
- No he obtenido buenas calificaciones.

Nota la diferencia entre *las mejores calificaciones* y *buenas calificaciones*. El primero es el mejor entre todos (*the best*); el segundo es sencillamente bueno (*good*).

Answer (score 8):

Agregar un simple *sí* me parece la opción más obvia.

> No obtengo las mejores calificaciones, aunque sí estudio bastante.
>
> No me gusta escuchar música, aunque sí toco el clarinete.

Esto también podría funcionar bien cuando se utiliza en inglés para negar una implicación de una acción en negativo.

> -¿No comes nada?
>    - No como mucho, pero *sí* como (but I *do* eat).

Comment: Gracias, no sabía que se puede utilizar 'sí' para ello. ¿Es mejor de decir "No obtengo las mejores calificaciones" que "No estás consiguiendo buenas notas"? (He utilizado traductor Google para eso frase ;-) )

Comment: No. Tu versión está perfectamente bien. Tuve que poner una versión propia porque en la aplicación móvil no se puede ver la pregunta cuando se redacta una respuesta :p